# View models shared between WPF and Blazor in a .NET Standard project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, blazor, .net-standard

Is it possible to keep a view models in a .NET Standard project?

I would like to have a common view models for two different applications: one written in WPF and the second one in Blazor.
The problem appeared when I wanted to invoke my ICommand's event `CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` in a separate thread and got an error: "System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.". I don't see Dispatcher support in .NET Standard, or any alternative to it. Can such view models be shared between different platforms (eg. Windows, Mac and Linux) at all?

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea.  Assuming SPA, the way I would try to implement this would be to register a class with the dependency injection that would stand in for the ICommand.
The example code is from a class that has ballooned from a small suggestion I found on the web to a lot of functionality.

I have just snipped out a few pieces of code, if you want to try it this way and you need more info, let me know I will give a complete in code answer.

The @onclick method on the button could then call a method that raises the event in the injected class.
The subscribing class could be on the same Component or anywhere else.

Also if your WPF isn't one of those where the developer is showing off how well they understand WPF you should be able to write a script that would go a long ways towards automating this conversion.

On a side note I definitely see the Resemblance of Blazor Serverside with WPF.  To me it is as if WPF got a long due update and it is improved in nearly every area.  I too approach it as if it was WPF, but I don't try to do a straight conversion because it is so improved.

```
 public void ShowNotification(NotificationMessage notificationMessage)
    {
        Message = notificationMessage;
        NotifyMessageArrived();
    }

     
    private void NotifyMessageArrived()
    {
        OnRaiseMessageArrivedNotification?.Invoke();
    }
 public event Action OnRaiseMessageArrivedNotification;
```